# Controlling the size of cells in a table

Tags: tables

How can I control the size of the cells in the following table?

```
\documentclass{article}
    %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage{array}
    %\usepackage{wrapfig}
    %\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{tabular}
        
    \usepackage{makecell}   
    \setcellgapes{7pt}
    
    \begin{document}
    
$\alpha$\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{%
                   @{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{4.5ex}}%
                   *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr3ex-\tabcolsep}|}%
                  }
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$j$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$k$} \\
\cline{2-4}
$i$ &  T  &  F  &  T  \\
\cline{2-4}
$j$ &  T  &  F  &  T  \\
\cline{2-4}
$k$ &  F  &  T  &  F \\[-\arrayrulewidth]
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}  

    \end{document}
```

When I compile the above code, the cells are not as small as in the picture here below (as I would like them to be):

[image]

Comment: you have tagged this tabularx and ask about tabularx in the title but your example does not use that environment at all?

Comment: @David Carlisle: I've changed that.

Answer (score 1):

With `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2mm,cell-space-bottom-limit=1.5mm}

$B$\quad \begin{NiceTabular}[baseline=0]{ccc}%
  [first-row,first-col,hvlines, columns-width=3.5mm]
& $i$ & $j$ & $k$ \\
$i$ &  T  &  F  &  T  \\
$j$ &  T  &  F  &  T  \\
$k$ &  F  &  T  &  F \\
\end{NiceTabular}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
$\alpha$\quad 
\begin{tabular}[t]{*{4}{c|}}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$j$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$k$} \\
\cline{2-4}
$i$ &  T  &  F  &  T  \\
\cline{2-4}
$j$ &  T  &  F  &  T  \\
\cline{2-4}
$k$ &  F  &  T  &  F \\
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}  
\end{document}
```

---

Here is also an laternatie using a tikz matrix. You can control the hieght and width of the cells as well as the distance between letter and cell border using the options `minimum height`, `minimum width`, and `inner sep` :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix(table)[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center, 
         minimum width=0.4cm,
         minimum height=0.4cm, 
         fill=none, 
         draw=black, 
         inner sep=0pt},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={draw=none}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
  ] 
  {    & $i$ & $j$ & $k$  \\
   $i$ & T   & F   & T    \\
   $j$ & T   & F   & T    \\
   $k$ & F   & T   & F    \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```